# Is it correct to use $P=\large\frac{V^2}{R}$ for AC circuits?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, voltage

In one of my old notebooks, I found a problem which was basically about finding out resistance of a 100W light bulb (In my country electricity voltage is 220V). Then our teacher had used the equation $P=\large\frac{V^2}{R}$ as solution. He had substituted $P=100W$, and $V=220V$ and found $R=484\Omega$.

But isn't this solution wrong? I think it should be wrong, because we are talking about AC here; That is, 220V is *peak voltage*, not *mean voltage*. I think that mean voltage is something below 220V, thus resistance is going to be below 484 Ohms.

Is this conclusion right?

Comment: No, AC voltages are typically measured as root mean square values. Ohm's law applies instantaneously $P(t) = V(t)^2/R$ and the point of RMS voltages is so that you can  use RMS voltages / currents in Ohm's law: you take time averages of both sides of the equation. So the amplitude of the supply voltage is in fact $220\,\sqrt{2}{\rm V}$, about 311V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing to watch out for here is that it is easy to get into the habit of using sloppy language and/or notion for these things.

I'll try to be precise here.

It is *correct* to use the above relationship for the *instantaneous* power developed by a resistive component in a AC circuit
$$ P(t) = \frac{(V(t))^2}{R} \,. $$
Of course, that power will fluctuate between zero and some peak value $V_0^2/R$ ($V(t) = V_0 \sin(\omega t)$ or similar) at twice the frequency of the AC. For many day to day application that is faster than we care about and we want the *average* power. We compute (using $T$ for the period so that $\omega T = 2 \pi$):
$$\begin{align*}
 \bar{P} 
&= \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^T P(t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{T} \frac{V_0^2}{R} \int_{t=0}^{T} \sin^2 (\omega t) \,\mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi} \frac{V_0^2}{R} \int_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \sin^2 (2 \pi \theta / T) (2\pi) \,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \frac{V_0^2}{2R} \,.
\end{align*}
$$
We're tantalizingly close, now because the average power is related to the the square of the peak voltage divided by the resistance, but there is a pesky factor of 2 in there.

Finally, we note that the RMS (root-mean-square) voltage is $V_{RMS} = V_0/\sqrt{2}$, which lets us write
$$ \bar{P} = \frac{V_{RMS}^2}{R} \,.$$

The process by which we got here is very general, so we can apply the RMS values of voltage and current in all the relationships between those quantities and power as long as we are willing to consider the average power.

---

So back to your question *"But isn't this wrong?"* The answer depend on which $V$ is $220\,\mathrm{V}$. It is conventional in AC applications for quantities quoted without modifier to mean the RMS values, and to require a modifier (say "peak") if you mean the maximum values (i.e. $V_0$ is the "peak voltage").

This brings us to Rod's comment. When the power supply from the wall is indicated as "220 volts" they really mean the RMS value is 220. From which you can find the peak value to be $V_0 = \sqrt{2} V_{RMS} \approx 311 \,\mathrm{V}$.

---

Showing the relationship between peak and RMS values of a sinusoidal quantity is another integral similar to the one we did above.
$$\begin{align*}
V_{RMS} &= \sqrt{\bar{V}}\\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^T \left( V(t) \right)^2 \,\mathrm{d}t \right]^{1/2}\\
&= \left[ \frac{1}{T} \int_{t=0}^T V_0^2 \sin^2 (\omega t) \,\mathrm{d}t \right]^{1/2}\\&= \left[ \frac{V_0^2}{2} \right]^{1/2}\\
&= \frac{V_0}{\sqrt{2}} \,.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Actually, you seem to have finessed the whole question of peak vs RMS. Your square root of 2 factor only applies to pure sines, and your last section does not show what you seem to think it does, as no sine function appears in it.

Comment: I had elided several lines in computing the RMS value because they are the same as above: $V(t) = V_0 \sin \omega t$, but I'll add one more in for clarity's sake. It does show what I want. You are right about the need for real sinusoids to make it come out exactly, but at the level of the question I'm willing to go with that.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that 220V-AC means that voltage difference is alternating between ±220V, but now it clears out that 220V is the mean voltage (as you said, RMS, to be precise) and voltage actually alternates between ~ ±311. And either using 220V as RMS voltage or finding average power using 311V, both will get the correct result. Is this conclusion right?

Comment: @MoctavaFarzán Yes, that's the way.

Answer (score 1):

> But isn't this solution wrong? I think it should be wrong, because we
>   are talking about AC here; That is, **220V is peak voltage**, not mean
>   voltage. I think that mean voltage is something below 220V, thus
>   resistance is going to be below 484 Ohms.

If you do not live in central or north america, 220V will be RMS, so your teacher is right.

Comment: This point was covered in the comment under the question and in the above answer. This post is better suited as a comment, but given that the issue was already addressed, I'm not sure what it would add as a comment